# recover an element by based on his children with only selector

Tags: javascript, html, css

**What I need :** Getting an Element that has checked checkbox children with only selector.

Actually I can retrieve the inputs as follows

```
 document.querySelectorAll('tr>td>input[type=checkbox]:checked')
```

I would like to know if there is a way to retrieve the "tr" element without having to cycle through the various input elements and retrieve the closest parent

Comment: can you share the html?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: could you explain what do you mean by "with only selector"?